C0 control set availability
Is it true that all C0 control characters (ASCII codes 0x00-0x1F) are available in all present character sets and can be represented in all encodings?
If no, what are examples of those encodings/character sets?

No, it is false, or it depends.
The C0 means control character set 0, and we had methods to select which control character to put there (on some set of characters/encoding). The only requirements were about ESC position (so you can change the set of characters). Obviously it works just for character set with were compatible with such encoding structure (and so where using the name C0 make sense). So not all encoding, but all ASCII based one uses the first 32 codes for control characters. [Note: font may define other characters there, but it is a different story].
Usually we use one specific C0: the IRV, or ISO 646, and as you may notice, many control codes are no (more) defined in modern ASCII. You get a list of possible control character sets in https://itscj.ipsj.or.jp/english/vbcqpr00000004qn-att/ISO-IR.pdf but apart of ESC (and SPACE and a control character in position 127) there is little restrictions.
Note: the meaning of control code in C0 is not much standardized. E.g. the most obvious: e.g. \0 (00) is meant to be a placeholder, to be ignored (e.g. keyboards or modem can regularly send one character to keep them connected, or when one do not complete a sequence). But now C and so many other languages uses it as termination. \c and \r (and so \n have different interpretation). Backspace (so not really a C0 was originally used in ASCII to compose characters, now ASCII do not have such composite characters. FF (form feed), so new page, it may be used by some code editor to split regions.
So: you can assume control codes are there (but if you work on very old encodings). But different system may interpret it differently, and so Unicode is not standardizing it (and there are regularly question in Unicode about TELETEXT, and other system which uses C0 very differently as ASCII).
